# Flutter Ошибка при вставке StatefulWidget в ListView

Tags: flutter

В приложении есть класс наследник StatefullWidget,  в методе Widget build(BuildContext context) которого выводится ListView

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {

        return ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          children: <Widget>[
            _MyStatefulWidget(),
          ],
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

а в ListView я пытаюсь вывести другой класс наследник StatefullWidget

```
  class _MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() =>
      _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<_MyStatefulWidget> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      
    );
  }
}
```

Но получаю ошибку

> RenderRepaintBoundary object was given an infinite size during layout.

Как это исправить?

Comment: некорректно использовать `Scaffold` внутри `Scaffold`

Comment: а ошибка говорит о том, что дочерний виджет пытается получить размер с родительского виджета, у которого неопределенный размер

Answer (score 0):

> а ошибка говорит о том, что дочерний виджет пытается получить размер с
> родительского виджета, у которого неопределенный размер – @zakiroof

Используйте [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) или задайте размер для `_MyStatefulWidget`